# make struct from json

Tags: json, swift, struct, alamofire

im trying to make a  struct with this result of alamofire (it is not all the result, but its the part where it breaks):

```
weather =     (
                {
            description = "clear sky";
            icon = 01d;
            id = 800;
            main = Clear;
        }
    );
```

In Xcode i have:

```
struct NameWeatherResponse: Codable {
    ...
    var coord: Coord?
    var weather: Weather?
   ...
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var main, weatherDescription, icon: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, main
        case weatherDescription = "description"
        case icon
    }
}
```

i have also tryed:

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var main, description, icon: String?

    
}
```

if i comment in NameWeatherResponse the variable weather it all works correct,

Comment: `weather` is an array. Catch the DecodingError and print it. It's pretty descriptive.

Comment: Have you made sure that all the types used in `NameWeatherResponse` conform to `Codable`? Also, have you tried using the `JSONDecoder` built into Swift's Foundation?

Comment: Thank you all, specially to vadian, just make the declaration as an array and when i access it al works perfect.